# Append 1D list to 2D list and make a 3D list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, append

I have two lists **list1** and **list2**

```
list1 = [[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [3,4,5]]
list2 = [0,1,2]
```

I'm supposed to get a new list **list3** as

```
list3 = [list1, list2]
```

or more precisely

```
list3 = [[[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [3,4,5]], [0,1,2]]
```

When I try `l1.append(l2)` it gives `[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2]]`
Which in not what I want

Comment: What's wrong with what you already have: `list3 = [list1, list2]`?

Comment: What about `list3 = [list1, list2]` did not work?

Comment: I'm doing further manipulation on data which requires the above shape which I mentioned.

Comment: Yeah, It worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have answered it yourself

```
list3 = [list1, list2]
```

Answer (score 2):

You are supposed to do something like this

```
l3 = []
l3.append(list1)
l3.append(list2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your answer just does what you requested but you can also do:

```
list3 = [list1]+[list2]
```

Answer (score 1):

in python a list can have as an element another list or list of lists, so you can do:

```
list3 = [list1, list2]
```